# iPhone tap to next page event

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, tap

I just wonder how can I achieve the gesture of tapping the lower right (left) corner of the screen to go to the next (previous) page in a UIScrollView, just like it did in the iBook apps from Apple?

Thanks,
Lawrence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try putting a UITapGestureRecognizer on the UIScrollView. If the tap location within the view is where you want, turn the page left or right.

[UITapGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)